# control of legends in GGplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a data.frame, but on the legends the size is added. How do i control the size of the dots without adding size to the legends?

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("peter", "peter", "peter", "peter", "jacob", "jacob"),
        test =c(10,8,4,2,7,5),
         something =c(100,80,40,20,77,55)
        )

df2 <- data.frame(name = c("Greg", "Lisa"),
              test =c(11,3.5),
              something =c(102,35)
             )

ggplot(df1, aes(x=test, y=something, color= name,size = 3)) +
  geom_point()+
 geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=test, y=something, color= name, size=7))
```

Comment: Try putting the `size` argument outside the `aes()` call.e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(x=test, y=something, color= name), size = 3) `

Comment: if i do this, the size are not 3 .. but 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just specify `size` in `geom_point()` itself:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(name = c("peter", "peter", "peter", "peter", "jacob", "jacob"),
                 test =c(10,8,4,2,7,5),
                 something =c(100,80,40,20,77,55)
)


ggplot(df, aes(x=test, y=something, color= name)) +
    geom_point(size = 3)
```

[image]

### Update

In case you need **all** your point sizes to be 3 instead of just in this *one* call to `geom_point()`, you can just update the default size:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=test, y=something, color= name)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(size = 3))

ggplot(df, aes(x=test, y=something, color= name)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

### Update 2:

In the updated question, you can still specify `size` per `geom_point()` call, so long as you put it *outside* the `aes()` wrapper:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=test, y=something, color= name)) +
    geom_point(size = 3)+
    geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=test, y=something, color= name), size=7)
```

[image]

Comment: the probelm with this solution is that if i add more datasets, where i need to adjust size.. then its impossible

Comment: @SorenStillingChristensen I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. You mean if you have more calls to `geom_point()`?

Comment: @SorenStillingChristensen See the updates to the answer; that might address the issue you're still worried about

Comment: see my new example.. its really about controlling the size of the plot individually

Comment: @SorenStillingChristensen In your second example, you would just put the size *within* the new `geom_point()` call, but *outside* the `aes()` wrapper. Posting update momentarily